# Google Script To Remove All Text After A Keyword

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting some extra date and time info in Column A (starting with row 2) that I need to remove because it is preventing some Duration calculations.  All the rows in Column A are getting the 'GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)' appended after the actual Day and Time.

So what I'm trying to do with the following code is remove all the text after the space just before 'GMT' (so there's no trailing space remaining afterward).  I'm getting a circular dependency error, and understandably so since I'm inserting the formula into the cell that contains the data.  How can I avoid this and just remove that pesky GMT stuff from every row in column A?  Thanks in advance!

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have this date and time in a cell:

```
Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Savings)
```

And I want it to become:

```
Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05
```

My code is currently:

```
function RemoveGMT() {

// Get Source Spreadsheet
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get Source Sheet from Spreadsheet
var source_sheet = source.getActiveSheet();

// Get Last Row
var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();

// Insert TRIM Formula Into Every Row Of Column A
source_sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula('=TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND("GMT",A2)))');
var FillDownRange = source_sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow);
source_sheet.getRange("A2").copyTo(FillDownRange);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert `GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` to `0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` in the column "A".

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function RemoveGMT() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  source_sheet.getRange("A2:A" + source_sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("GMT ").replaceAllWith("");
}
```

- In this modification, `GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` is converted to `0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)`. When your values includes `GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` and `GMT0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)`, please modify the last line as follows.

  ```
    source_sheet.getRange("A2:A" + source_sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("^GMT ?").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("");
  ```

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

### Added:

From OP's following replying,

> My goal is to remove everything after the GMT. So, my cell would go from: Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time) to: Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05

I couldn't notice that you wanted to convert `Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` to `Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05`. But, when I saw your script in your answer, it seems that you wanted to remove the value of `GMT -0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` from the cell value. So I think that your comment is different from your answer. And, in your script, for example, when the cell value os `Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT -0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`, when your script is used, this value becomes `Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT` . The last space cannot be removed. And also, I think that when TextFinder is used for searching values, the process cost can be reduced from the method for searching from the retrieved array with `getValues`. So as the modified script for your situation, I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, from your replying of `My goal is to remove everything after the GMT. So, my cell would go from: Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time) to: Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05` and your script of `var to_replace = "GMT -0800 (Pacific Standard Time)";`,  `GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` and `GMT -0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` are removed from the cell values.

```js
function RemoveGMT() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  source_sheet.getRange("A2:A" + source_sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(" ?GMT.+$").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("");
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, sorry if I was unclear.  My goal is to remove everything after the GMT.

So, my cell would go from:

Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)

to:

Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05

Comment: @user1509059 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice that you wanted to convert `Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05 GMT 0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)` to `Nov. 27 2021 19:00:05`. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. For this, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question again, I apologize again.

Comment: @user1509059 By the way, although I'm not sure whether this direction is included in your goal, for example, in your situation, when you can achieve your goal using the built-in formula, a formula like `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A," ?GMT.+",""))` might be able to be also used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code, I'm just searching for the whole GMT part of the string and replacing it with "".

```
function RemoveGMT(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dell")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow)
  var to_replace = "GMT -0800 (Pacific Standard Time)";
  var replace_with = "";
  var data  = range.getValues();
 
    var oldValue="";
    var newValue="";
    var cellsChanged = 0;
 
    for (var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
      for (var i=0; i<data[r].length; i++) {
        oldValue = data[r][i];
        newValue = data[r][i].toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
        if (oldValue!=newValue)
        {
          cellsChanged++;
          data[r][i] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);
}
```